# How could the numerals יה and יו be used irreverently?

Tags: number, aleph-bet-letters, shemos-sacred-names

I was told that in the sequence of numerals with Hebrew letters, the numbers 15 and 16 are rendered with **טו** and  **טז** instead of **יה** and **יו** to prevent the tetragrammaton from being formed irreverently.

I'm not sure how this is possible: **יו** is not a substring of the tetragrammaton, and **יה** would have to be connected somehow with a **וה**, but **וה** isn't used numerically.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would add that this rule seems to be applied inconsistently as 31 is usually written aleph lamed.

Comment: Thirty one is never written as aleph-lamed...

Comment: It is not unheard-of to see י then ו as a numeral in older _s'farim_. Example: The _Shu"t Mahara"m Shik_, when the year is (5)616, uses תרי"ו.

Comment: hilariously related: http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-lists-20021107/#hebrew (NOTE: this is an old version of the spec)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

י and ה by themselves do form a Divine name, used in several places in the Bible (e.g., Ex. 17:16). All of the laws about not erasing a name of G-d apply to it as well (Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh De'ah 276:10).

As for י and ו, we do find those used as a representation of G-d's name in personal names like יוחנן (Yochanan/Johanan, "G-d is kind") and יוכבד (Yocheved/Jochebed, "G-d's honor"). True that there is no law (that I know of) against erasing this combination, but I guess people still considered it too close for comfort.

The point, in any case, is not so much that the numbers 15 and 16 might be used irreverently (they're numbers like any other), but that a piece of paper bearing these numbers, written as Divine names or something similar to them, might be thrown into the garbage or otherwise treated disrespectfully.

Comment: Is it just minhag to maintain the tradition in sefarim which are most certainly shaimos?

Comment: @TKKocheran: probably. Then, too, it would be confusing to write these numbers one way in print and a different way in ephemera.

Comment: If you intend to write יה as a number, why would it have any more kedusha than writing אלהים when referring to idols (or judges)?

Answer (score 2):

1. It's 15 and 16. Not 14 which is יד.
2. יה does represent one of god's name. It can be without the וה ending.
3. I don't know about יו