# Why do we write the number 16 as tet + zayin?

Tags: number, aleph-bet-letters, shemos-sacred-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could the numerals יה and יו be used irreverently?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/how-could-the-numerals-and-be-used-irreverently)

I understand that we write the number 15 as tet vav as opposed to yud hey to avoid writing the shem Hashem, but what about 16? As far as I know there is no shem Hashem that is yud, vav. What am I missing?

Comment: ha'bayishan, Welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for asking a question! (I'm sure this will prove to be a _learning_ experience for you.) Please consider registering your account so you can gain the full benefits of the site. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: If I understand, 16 as טז instead of יו is a relatively recent thing. I encounter יו in older writings all the time.

Comment: Like @jake I have also seen the writing yud-vav instead of tet-zayin. A quick search in Google revealed this from Sefer Harikma to Rabbi Jona Ben Ganach quoting from Yeshaya, Shemot and Yirmiya:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9357916/SE/yodvav.png .

Notice how the Rabbi refers to verse 16 as yod-vav but to chapter 16 as tet-zain. I don't really know why this is different but I can try and guess that it has something to do with the division of Mikra chapters being of Christian origins.

Comment: @smichak, I don't think those references are actually written by Ibn Janach; more likely added in by the publisher. Check out [this one](http://tinyurl.com/c7bgmgz) though, written much later, with 16 sometimes referred to as tet-zayin and sometimes as yud-vav in the text itself, although that could also be the result of the printer changing a bunch of them to reflect the current custom, but not catching all of them.