# Where can one find a complete guide to Hebrew numerals?

Tags: number, product-recommendation, hebrew, aleph-bet-letters, gematria-numerology

I am looking for an instruction resource on Hebrew numerals that is comprehensive, insofar as it:

- lists all (or nearly all) of the euphemistic exceptions in frequent use (such as "chai" for 18, רחץ instead of רצח, etc.)
- describes the protocol for reordering digits to avoid writing Hashem's name

and

- discusses what is done in speech, for example when certain numerals are read as words (i.e. "Lag"), and how one pronounces reordered numbers.

Can anyone refer me to such a resource? (...Or provide the information here?)

Comment: It should be noted that all these details are not Halakhic, but just somewhat common practice.

Comment: What constitutes "complete"? Every exception that is used by X% of people for some X?

Comment: `discusses what is done in speech, for example when certain numerals are read as words (i.e. "Lag"), and how one pronounces reordered numbers.` This seems like a matter of popular convention or usage that is not on topic here. || Do you have some reason to think that there is a single resource that addresses any or all of these seemingly unrelated matters of personal preference and practice?

Comment: Re "avoid writing Hashem's name" see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10692/3).

Answer (score 1):

1) [*The Wisdom in the Hebrew Alphabet*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899061931.html) by Michael L. Munk zt"l, page 221

2) [*Jewish Wisdom In The Numbers*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422613443.html) by Rabbi Yehoshua Hartman Osher Chaim Levene