# When did the gematria for 16 become ט"ז as oppose to י-ו?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

I've been going through some records (e.g. from the old Jewish cemetery in Worms, Germany) from the 1200's and 1300's, and I've noticed that the gematria for 16 is yud-vav, as opposed to tes-zayin.
When and why was this switch incorporated and became mainstream?
(I'm aware of the gematria for 15 being tes-vav universally, and I'm aware that it is because yud-hey is the Shem Hashem.)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/how-could-the-numerals-%d7%99%d7%94-and-%d7%99%d7%95-be-used-irreverently

Comment: I think "mainstream" is ill-defined when speaking about Halacha or a tradition. Different rabbis and different communities in different places adopted it differently, over about a millennia. IIRC even some Rishonim use יה or יו in their interpretations. BTW, check the festival of טו בשבט.

Comment: I think the Rashba uses יו.

Comment: I believe within Kabbalistic literature the י-ו combination is used in description of Hashem's Name (it being two of the letters of the Four Letter Name, same as י-ה is).