# Pasuk Numbering Question

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, gematria-numerology

Shalom! In the pasuk number of today's aliyah of the parsha I noticed something curious. Instead of counting yed-aleph - kaf as I would expect, it jumps to tet-vuv and tet-zayin, and then returned to the yud sequence of counting up to kaf. Is there an explanation for this? Toda raba!

[image: Page 1/2]

[image: Page 2/2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4940

Comment: To those thinking of marking this question as a duplicate of the [linked question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10682/4940): This question simply asks why the  tet-vuv and tet-zayin are there. The other question starts with _an_ answer to this question (i.e. there may be other answers), and asks a followup question about that specific answer.

Comment: Does the gematria of those two letter combinations share the same gematria as something negative?

Comment: I'm satisfied with the explanation after reading that post. It raises the question, does it really form The Name when it's separated by so much other text in between the two numbers?

Comment: Yes because the numbering for 15 i.e י-ה is a name for Hashem in unto itself.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. It does indeed. Just to clarify the Names of Hashem are written in many places in Torah. What is the rational of it being considered irreverent in this case? Maybe due to being written without a clear purpose?

Comment: @David more like "to avoid problems don't write it more than necessary"